# What are some difficult integrals done by substitution and elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

What are some examples of difficult integrals that are done using substitutions?

For example:  $$\int{\frac{(1+x^{2})dx}{(1-x^{2})\sqrt{1+x^{4}}}}$$

Please no laplace and fourier transforms as I haven't studied those yet.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you looking for examples of these sort of integrals, or are you looking for help with *this* integral?

Comment: I know how to do this, I am just looking for more integrals.

Comment: How do you do this one? Wolfram can't get an answer in terms of elementary functions

Comment: divide both numerator and denomerator by x^2 then use the substitution u=x+(1/x)

Comment: I'd like to see the details of how your example is solved.

Comment: I think it Is unsolvable by this method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a thread from AoPs that contains a good collection of indefinite integrals. You can find several non-trivial integrals done using substitution.

> **[Indefinite Integral Marathon](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=296&t=515012)**

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell if it is at the accepted answer's list, but $$\int\sqrt{\tan{x}}\,dx$$ is a good one. It's pretty concise, and perhaps at first it feels like either it is going to be very easy or not doable with elementary functions. It *is* doable with elementary functions and techniques, but it takes a fair amount of effort.

Answer (score 2):

Some More Questions $$\displaystyle \int \sqrt{\tan x}dx\;,\int\sqrt{\cot x}dx\;,\int \left(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}\right)dx\;,\int \left(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}\right)dx$$

$$\displaystyle \int\frac{1+x^4}{1+x^6}\;\;, \int\frac{1}{1+x^6}dx$$